# php css how to change name color based on membership?

Tags: php, html, css, colors

i want to create member badges on evolutionscript forum

**CSS :**

```css
.member_badge {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    background: #EEE;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.member_badge.admin {
    color: #000;
    background: #ee155d;
    border-color: #000;
}
.member_badge.moderator {
color: #FFF;
border-color: #050505;
background: #06e956;
}
```

**here is the TPL file (forum_topic.tpl)**

```html
{if $item.member.forum_role != 1}
      <tr>
              <td>
                    <div class="member_badge">
                                {$item.member.membership}
                    </div>
              </td>
      </tr>
{/if}
         
     
{if $item.member.forum_role != 1 && $item.member.forum_role != 3}
      <tr>
              <td class="member_badge moderator">
                    {$item.frmgroup.name}
              </td>
     </tr>
{/if}
```

how to make this `<td class="member_badge moderator">` if moderator logged

and how to set this  `<td class="member_badge ADMIN">` if admin logged
using php ?

look the image to understand what i mean

- admin badge
  http://7chaterz.com/r/admin.png
- moderator badge
  http://7chaterz.com/r/mod.png

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess "{$item.member.membership}" is returning the user's group name, right?

Then try this:

**CSS:**

```
.member_badge {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.admin {
    color: #000;
    background: #ee155d;
    border-color: #000;
}
.moderator {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #06e956;
    border-color: #050505;
}
```

**TPL:**

```
{if $item.member.forum_role != 1}
      <tr>
              <td>
                    <div class="member_badge {$item.member.membership}">
                                {$item.member.membership}
                    </div>
              </td>
      </tr>
{/if}


{if $item.member.forum_role != 1 && $item.member.forum_role != 3}
      <tr>
              <td class="member_badge moderator">
                    {$item.frmgroup.name}
              </td>
     </tr>
{/if}
```

Comment: so many thanks i didnt think that i can include PHP on CSS
<td class="member_badge  {$item.frmgroup.name}">
thanks again